# How can I add page numbers to the bottom of each page in a report using ActiveReports3?

Tags: activereports

I'm trying to understand how you are supposed to add page numbers to the bottom of each page using ActiveReports3.

E.g.

Page 1 of 10.

Thanks,

Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "ReportInfo" control and set the "FormatString" property.

Answer (score 8):

Use the ReportInfo object with the following FormatString

Page {PageNumber} of {PageCount}

You can also use the ReportInfo object to display the print time with this FormatString

Printed: {RunDateTime}

Answer (score 0):

There are two walkthroughs on how to do this at Data Dynamics website. You can see a link to both from the following page: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ar3oriPageNumberingWalkthroughs.html There is also an example of how to do this entirely in code from the following page: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ActiveReports3~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.ReportInfo.html